# Нестабильное Значение PHP Скрипта

Tags: php, строки, дата, php7

Скрипт который показываем дату и время в миллисекундах 
потом засыпает на `usleep(20000);`
И снова выводит дату

```
$microt = explode(" ",microtime());
    echo $time = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s",$microt[1]).substr((string)$microt[0],1,4);
    echo "<br>";

    usleep(20000);

$microt = explode(" ",microtime());
    echo $time = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s",$microt[1]).substr((string)$microt[0],1,4);
    echo "<br>";
```

//запускаем скрипт по очереди 3 раза
//вывод скрипта

```
//попытка 1
2016-10-28-20-29-57.909
2016-10-28-20-29-57.929

//попытка 2
2016-10-28-20-30-27.222
2016-10-28-20-30-27.243

//попытка 3
2016-10-28-20-30-51.911
2016-10-28-20-30-51.931
```

Попытка 1 и 3 отработали нормально , но попытка 2 вместо разницы в 0.20 вывел разницу в 0.21 , как видите скрипт больше ничем не занят , в чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Если не секрет, зачем вам такая точность?

Comment: результат будет присваиваться к имени файла т.к

//файл 1 example 2016-10-28-20-29-57.900
//файл 2 example 2016-10-28-20-29-57.920

//файл 3 example 2016-10-28-20-30-51.911
//файл 4 example 2016-10-28-20-30-51.931
а если будет не точно , то и не красиво будет смотреться в списке , но уже решил этот вопрос подругому

Comment: Без вяких шуток, мне будет очень интересно посмотреть на ваш проэкт когда вы его закончите. Когда закончите проэкт скиньте ссылку.

Comment: без проблем , это своя простенькая cms система с возможность дальнейшего развития

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не нова, и очень актуальна для realtime computing/systems.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing

Многие языки не дают достаточную точность по времени(прослойка OS, округления, преобразование типов, частота процессора не стабильна и постоянна немного плывет ...)

Так же, в вашем коде для вывода даты вы делаете достаточно "времезатратные" преоброзавания.

`expload`, `date`, `substr` - не самые быстрые функции добавьте к ним округление...

Если переписать ваш код:

```
<?php
    $t1 = microtime(true);
    usleep(20000);
    $t2 = microtime(true);

    echo $t2 - $t1;
```

Результат будет ближе к желаемому.

Запустил тест получилась погрешность в 10 раз менше чем у вас.

```
0.02014684677124                                                                                                                                                                                                   
0.020076990127563                                                                                                                                                                                                  
0.020087957382202                                                                                                                                                                                                  
0.020082950592041                                                                                                                                                                                                  
0.020128011703491                                                                                                                                                                                                  
0.020082950592041                                                                                                                                                                                                  
0.02009105682373                                                                                                                                                                                                   
0.02008581161499                                                                                                                                                                                                   
0.020123958587646                                                                                                                                                                                                  
0.020067930221558
```

Comment: ясно , без погрешности видимо никак совсем